# SCSS counter with nested divs

Tags: html, css, sass, css-counter

I have a problem with CSS and counter. The second `h3` should have the number "1.2" but in my case it has always the number "1.1".

Is this a problem with the divs around the h3 or did I make a mistake with the counter-reset? Thanks for your help! :)

I have the following HTML:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: counterh2;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: counterh3;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: counterh4;
}

h4 {
  counter-reset: counterh5;
}

.container {
  >h2::before,
  >.div>h2::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh2;
  }
  >h3::before,
  >.div>h3::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh3;
  }
  >h4::before,
  >.div>h4::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) "." counter(counterh4, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh4;
  }
  >h5::before,
  >.div>h5::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) "." counter(counterh4, decimal) "." counter(counterh5, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div">
    <h2><span>Should be 1</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h3><span>Should be 1.1</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h3><span>Should be 1.2</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The h2 that resets the h3counter is in a different container than the h3's. That means the h3counter will be in a different context than the h3's.

Solution: don't reset the counter in the h2, but in its parent .div, which is in the same container as the divs containing the h3's.

```css
.container .div:first-child {
  counter-reset: counterh3;
}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: counterh2;
}

.container .div:first-child {
  counter-reset: counterh3;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: counterh4;
}

h4 {
  counter-reset: counterh5;
}

.container>h2::before,
.container>.div>h2::before {
  content: counter(counterh2, decimal) ". ";
  counter-increment: counterh2;
}

.container>h3::before,
.container>.div>h3::before {
  content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) ". ";
  counter-increment: counterh3;
}

.container>h4::before,
.container>.div>h4::before {
  content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) "." counter(counterh4, decimal) ". ";
  counter-increment: counterh4;
}

.container>h5::before,
.container>.div>h5::before {
  content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) "." counter(counterh4, decimal) "." counter(counterh5, decimal) ". ";
  counter-increment: counterh5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div">
    <h2><span>Should be 1</span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h3><span>Should be 1.1</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h3><span>Should be 1.2</span></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: I had to translate the SCSS for this snippet, because snippet doesn't do SCSS, but you get the idea. All you need to replace is the first line of CSS I gave above.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It works better, but now the h3 counter never resets when a new h2 appears. This is my full HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h2><span>Hauptkapitel h2</span></h2>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h3><span>Unterkapitel h3</span></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h3><span>Unterkapitel h3</span></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h2><span>Hauptkapitel h2</span></h2>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h3><span>Unterkapitel h3</span></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h3><span>Unterkapitel h3</span></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h4><span>Unterkapitel h4</span></h4>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h4><span>Unterkapitel h4</span></h4>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h5><span>Unterkapitel h5</span></h5>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h5><span>Unterkapitel h5</span></h5>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h3><span>Unterkapitel h3</span></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-text-unit">
        <h2><span>Hauptkapitel h2</span></h2>
        <div>
            <p>Sed sit amet elit scelerisque, tempor dui non, pharetra augue. Mauris fringilla sem sed magna molestie dignissim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And SASS:

```
body {
  counter-reset: counterh2;
}

.container .article-text-unit:first-child {
  counter-reset: counterh3;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: counterh4;
}

h4 {
  counter-reset: counterh5;
}

.container {
  > h2::before,
  > .article-text-unit > h2::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh2;
  }
  > h3::before,
  > .article-text-unit > h3::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh3;
  }
  > h4::before,
  > .article-text-unit > h4::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) "." counter(counterh4, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh4;
  }
  > h5::before,
  > .article-text-unit > h5::before {
    content: counter(counterh2, decimal) "." counter(counterh3, decimal) "." counter(counterh4, decimal) "." counter(counterh5, decimal) ". ";
    counter-increment: counterh5;
  }
}
```